# Can I paint my entire Class C RV using fluorescent green and how long will the paint job last

Tags: ford, paint, exterior, econoline, rv

I cannot afford to paint my 30 year old RV (in which I rebuilt the engine and plan on going on a Road Trip around the world!) professionaly ... Can I paint my entire Class C RV using Rustoleum fluorescent green if no rust, what will be the result and how long will the paint job last ?? What else do I need to do ? Thanks in advance for any info or opinions !!

Answer (score 11):

You absolutely can!  I've painted several of my race cars this way, on a limited budget.  The looked wonderful, and I usually wrecked them before the paint was an issue.

If you prep very well (all automotive paintjobs are 90% prep work, and 10% spraying) you can get outstanding results.  You do need to have some painting experience, even with a rattlecan. It will not last as long as automotive paint, but it will look nice for years and last years after that.

Two possible caveats:

1. Flourecent green has a terrible ability to cover.  You either need to prime first in white or grey, or spray on an already light existing color.  Note that any variation in color (rust, bondo patch, something unpainted or sanded) will show through clear as day.  The base [primer] coat needs to be uniform.  Existing paint needs to be "roughed up" and thouroughly cleaned with solvents and tack rags before spraying.  Outdoors, you need perfect cool, windless weather, and a lack of insects is really helpful.  Conditions that are rarely, if ever, available.
2. If you ever desire a professional automotive paint job, every last trace of "Rustoleum" will have to be stripped.  Rustoleum formulations have oils or magic chemicals which resist corrosion, but they also make it difficult for other paints to stick to it.  It will cost extra and the bodyman will curse you (ask me how I know).  However, if a "real" paint job or budget is never in the forseable cards, spray away.

You're going to need a *bunch* of rattlecans.  Again, flourecent green has poor coverage, will require multiple coats, and it sounds like you have a lot of area to cover.

Do some thinking, you might find that an "Earl Scheib" or "Macco" type low-budget job won't be much more than the cost of 20 cans of primer and 30 cans of green.

Comment: Also, consider getting a inexpensive HVLP sprayer and paint in "bulk" (gallons or quarts). It could well be less expensive.

Comment: Also consider fluorescent green will not stand up to UV light outdoors for very long. It will degrade faster than other colors.

Comment: How do you know? :D

Comment: Thats Earl Shibe...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earl_Scheib

Comment: @Moab  Evidently It's actually Earl *Scheib*.   Thank you for the opportunity to clarify.

Comment: Exactly the type of goofy-yet-informative answer I expected for such a goofy-yet-legitimate question.

Answer (score 3):

Can you do it? Yes.

Will you ever lose your vehicle in a car park? No. Not in a million years.

Is it a good idea? Well, you're going to do the prep yourself anyway. Strip and prep to a rolling chassis, and get a quote from a local paint shop for a blow-over in the original color (or close to it). It may be surprisingly close in price to the cost of the rustoleum or painting equipment you'd need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

90% of a good paint job is in the body work. Unless the body work is done flawlessly you will see every ding. Just about anyone a can paint a car it's the body work that counts. I would go with a white color paint, it hides the more. The paint should last a few years. You maybe be better off doing the body work yourself (flawlessly) and then getting a paint job with Maaco for the same price of all those paint cans.